# how to write a procedure inside package body in oracle - error?

Tags: oracle

I have this package where I'm adding some values into the table,this works....

```
create or replace PACKAGE BODY DC_LOAN_PKG
IS
PROCEDURE loan_book 
(
  loan_id IN DC_LOAN_EVIDENCE.ID%type,
  b_id    IN DC_LOAN_EVIDENCE.BOOK_ID%type,
  m_id    IN DC_LOAN_EVIDENCE.MEMBER_ID%type,
  d_ofl   IN DC_LOAN_EVIDENCE.DATE_OF_LOAN%type)
IS
BEGIN
  INSERT
  INTO DC_LOAN_EVIDENCE
  (
    ID,
    BOOK_ID,
    MEMBER_ID,
    DATE_OF_LOAN
  )
  VALUES
  (
    DC_SEQ.NEXTVAL,
    b_id,
    m_id,
    SYSDATE
  );
  COMMIT;
END loan_book;
```

now, I want to write procedures return_book and extend_loan inside which I want to get DATE when the book is returned and a new date of loan after extending. What I'm doing wrong? Here is the example....

```
PROCEDURE return_book
  (
    b_id  IN DC_LOAN_EVIDENCE.BOOK_ID%type,
    m_id  IN DC_LOAN_EVIDENCE.MEMBER_ID%type,
    r_dat IN DC_LOAN_EVIDENCE.RETURN_DATE%type
  )
IS
  dStartDate DATE := TO_DATE('2014-12-23', 'YYYY-MM-DD');
  dEndDate   DATE := TO_DATE('2015-01-23', 'YYYY-MM-DD');
BEGIN
  UPDATE DC_LOAN_EVIDENCE
  SET RETURN_DATE =r_dat
  WHERE MEMBER_ID =m_id
  AND BOOK_ID     =b_id
  AND RETURN_DATE BETWEEN dStartDate AND dEndDate ;
  COMMIT;
END return_book;
PROCEDURE extend_loan
  (
    b_id  IN DC_LOAN_EVIDENCE.BOOK_ID%type,
    m_id  IN DC_LOAN_EVIDENCE.MEMBER_ID%type,
    d_ofl   IN DC_LOAN_EVIDENCE.DATE_OF_LOAN%type
  )
IS
BEGIN
  UPDATE DC_LOAN_EVIDENCE
  SET DATE_OF_LOAN =d_ofl
  WHERE MEMBER_ID =m_id
  AND BOOK_ID     =b_id;
  COMMIT;
END extend_loan;
END DC_LOAN_PKG;
```

Comment: Is there a compiler error or what exactly is the problem? Any error message?

Comment: No, the code is doesn't right! When I want to execute procedure it gives me nothing?!?

Comment: Error??? What error? I don't see any error in your question.

Comment: it's not error. I just can't invoke the procedures, it gives me nothing. Can you help me and maybe write example how can I do that?

Comment: What does 'it gives me nothing' mean though? When you execute the procedure it seems to run but the row in the table isn't updated as you expect? Are you calling it with values that already exist (and are committed) in the table? Or are you expecting some kind of response showing the new date?

Comment: When I execute the procedure it seems to run but the row in the table isn't updated as I'm expecting. I want to update column that gives me new date (when the book is returned - RETURN_DATE).

Comment: Are you calling the procedure from the same session you can see the data exists in the table; if not is it committed? Assuming the data exists, are you passing the arguments in the right order? An update won't error if it does no work, so it seems likely you're just giving it the wrong values. A complete test case would help, or show you what is wrong as you create it.

Comment: I don't know, I just know that procedure return_book when I pass arguments doesn't give me RETURN_DATE as I ask it.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your original procedure, `loan_book`, has two parameters you don't use - whatever you pass as `id` and `book_loan_date` is ignored, and is replaced by the sequence value and current date respectively. Using a sequence for the ID makes sense but letting users pass in their own value will be confusing, so you should maybe remove that argument. Whether you use `sysdate` or the passed value for the date of the loan depends on your business rules, but at the moment that is also confusing at best. A compromise might be to have that argument default to `sysdate`, so it can be overridden if needed.

Your `return_book` procedure is not going to match any records created by `loan_book` because it's checking the `return_date`, which will be null (unless you've already set it manually in the meantime); that check seems rather odd if you can only return a loan once. Essentially, `AND RETURN_DATE BETWEEN dStartDate AND dEndDate` will not match any rows where `return_date` is null.

Your `extend_loan` procedure does seem to be working though, assuming you're passing the right book and member values.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/ebc3e/1).

If you are not seeing the `date_of_loan` being extended then you must be passing the wrong values to the procedure.

However, passing the book and member to your new procedures implies that a book can only be loaned to a member once. If you want to allow the same book to be borrowed more than once you should be passing the ID value instead, as that is (presumably!) unique. Perhaps your `return_date` filter in `return_book` is actually supposed to be checking the `date_of_loan` is recent, in an attempt to fix that ambiguity. Passing ID instead would be better; explicitly looking for non-returned books, and/or the most recent loan for a specific book/member, would work to some extent too but would be less robust.

It's also generally considered bad practice to commit inside a procedure, it's better to let the caller decide whether to commit or rollback.

Answer (score 2):

You need to keep the inner procedure in the declaration block of the main procedure.

Something like -

```
PROCEDURE return_book(
    b_id  IN DC_LOAN_EVIDENCE.BOOK_ID%type,
    m_id  IN DC_LOAN_EVIDENCE.MEMBER_ID%type,
    r_dat IN DC_LOAN_EVIDENCE.RETURN_DATE%type )
IS
  dStartDate DATE := TO_DATE('2014-12-23', 'YYYY-MM-DD');
  dEndDate   DATE := TO_DATE('2015-01-23', 'YYYY-MM-DD');
      PROCEDURE extend_loan(
          b_id  IN DC_LOAN_EVIDENCE.BOOK_ID%type,
          m_id  IN DC_LOAN_EVIDENCE.MEMBER_ID%type,
          d_ofl IN DC_LOAN_EVIDENCE.DATE_OF_LOAN%type )
      IS
      BEGIN
        UPDATE DC_LOAN_EVIDENCE
        SET DATE_OF_LOAN =d_ofl
        WHERE MEMBER_ID  =m_id
        AND BOOK_ID      =b_id;
        COMMIT;
      END extend_loan;
BEGIN
  UPDATE DC_LOAN_EVIDENCE
  SET RETURN_DATE =r_dat
  WHERE MEMBER_ID =m_id
  AND BOOK_ID     =b_id
  AND RETURN_DATE BETWEEN dStartDate AND dEndDate ;
  COMMIT;
END return_book;
END DC_LOAN_PKG;
```

I would insist you wrap it in a package. With such stand alone procedure, you are introducing the dependency chain. Which could be avoided using a package. You could implement encapsulation and it has many advantages just like Tom Kyte said -

- break the dependency chain (no cascading invalidations when you install a new package body -- if 
  you have procedures that call procedures -- compiling one will invalidate your database)
- support encapsulation -- I will be allowed to write MODULAR, easy to understand code -- rather 
  then MONOLITHIC, non-understandable procedures
- increase my namespace measurably.  package names have to be unique in a schema, but I can have 
  many procedures across packages with the same name without colliding
- support overloading
- support session variables when you need them
- promote overall good coding techniques, stuff that lets you write code that is modular, 
  understandable, logically grouped together....

**EDIT** If you have the procedures independent, then you need to have them separately.

```
CREATE OR replace PACKAGE BODY dc_loan_pkg 
IS 
  -- Procedure 1 
  PROCEDURE Loan_book(loan_id IN dc_loan_evidence.id%TYPE, 
                      b_id    IN dc_loan_evidence.book_id%TYPE, 
                      m_id    IN dc_loan_evidence.member_id%TYPE, 
                      d_ofl   IN dc_loan_evidence.date_of_loan%TYPE) 
  IS 
  BEGIN 
      INSERT INTO dc_loan_evidence 
                  (id, 
                   book_id, 
                   member_id, 
                   date_of_loan) 
      VALUES      ( dc_seq.NEXTVAL, 
                   b_id, 
                   m_id, 
                   SYSDATE ); 

      COMMIT; 
  END loan_book; 
  -- Procedure 2 
  PROCEDURE Return_book (b_id  IN dc_loan_evidence.book_id%TYPE, 
                         m_id  IN dc_loan_evidence.member_id%TYPE, 
                         r_dat IN dc_loan_evidence.return_date%TYPE) 
  IS 
    dstartdate DATE := To_date('2014-12-23', 'YYYY-MM-DD'); 
    denddate   DATE := To_date('2015-01-23', 'YYYY-MM-DD'); 
  BEGIN 
      UPDATE dc_loan_evidence 
      SET    return_date = r_dat 
      WHERE  member_id = m_id 
             AND book_id = b_id 
             AND return_date BETWEEN dstartdate AND denddate; 

      COMMIT; 
  END return_book; 
  -- Procedure 3 
  PROCEDURE Extend_loan(b_id  IN dc_loan_evidence.book_id%TYPE, 
                        m_id  IN dc_loan_evidence.member_id%TYPE, 
                        d_ofl IN dc_loan_evidence.date_of_loan%TYPE) 
  IS 
  BEGIN 
      UPDATE dc_loan_evidence 
      SET    date_of_loan = d_ofl 
      WHERE  member_id = m_id 
             AND book_id = b_id; 

      COMMIT; 
  END extend_loan; 
END dc_loan_pkg; 
/
```

Comment: @Sathya, thanks for the formatting and edit. I would like to know why highlighting using backtick is not appropriate? Without highlighting the Oracle keywords, it makes the entire message reading lethargic.

Comment: Backticks are intended for inline code formatting, excessive use of those harms your answer. I'll let you read this answer which pretty much explains why you should not do it. http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/194664/133693

Comment: Thanks for the link... Good moderation.

Comment: Surely the question has them already in a package (`END DC_LOAN_PKG;'), and the OP is adding two new procedure to an existing package? Your second code block seems to be what the OP already has, I think?

Comment: I didn't see the create package body statement earlier, may be i didn't see it as it wasn't included in the code formatting.